# OpenId and OpenAuth with mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, oauth, openid

I need to login with facebookx, twitter, gmail, openid, yahoo and other site in MVC3. 
I already search for Openauth and openID but could not get the proper solution. come solution run and went to the site but never come back with identty.

So can i get the proper solution in running mode with MVC3. Also please provide me the dll and also nuget template or packages details.

Can i test with localhost for openauth/openid?

Comment: This is not a `gimme the codez` type of site. If you had problem with a solution like `dotnetopenauth` then tell us the exact error

Answer (score 0):

**In short**, Yes you can test and host on local host.

What you need to focus is a Tokens that are managed in OAuth library provider of your choice. Just follow the wiki and some tutorial and you will be fine.

As a start point look at the [**dotnetopenaut.net source library**](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)  that brings **OpenID, OAuth, and ICard capabilities** to the Microsoft .NET Framework.

Reference: look at this post for more details: [OpenID and OAuth using DotNetOpenAuth in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/openid-and-oauth-using-dotnetopenauth-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I already download it but could not load with my vs 2010. it ask for web installer. i already trid to in install that but could not get any thing....please can you tell me the requirment for this... and if you have any sample code then please send me.

Comment: you don't need to download anything, just use NuGet packages.i have add a reference to the post that you need to follow.